# Freeradius 3.0.20 mysql radacct tamble empty not storing logs

Tags: mysql, freeradius

I am developing a small project using freeradius 3.0.20 on linux ubuntu 20.04 machine..
installed freeradius, configured mysql on default.conf... loaded virtual servers.. and my device can connect ok..

On init i can see NAS information being loaded from MYSQL table, info is stored everything ok..
client data stored in radcheck, radgroupgcheck,radgroupreply,radipool storing the cgnat ip table etc..

client device logs in with username and password all ok i can navigate on the internet with client logged in, but its not storing clients data on the accounting radacct table on the mysql... no history logs stored at all .. only thing i can see is radpostauth storing username, password xored md5 and authdate which contains the login date only.. attached below full log init from freeradius -x

if anyone can comment, or knows how to fix this configuration issue..

```
root@PSI-DEV:~# sudo freeradius -X
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.20
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
Starting - reading configuration files ...
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.dhcp
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.vqp
including dictionary file /etc/freeradius/3.0/dictionary
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/radiusd.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/proxy.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf
including files in directory /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/linelog
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/digest
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/echo
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/radutmp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/passwd
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/mschap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/unix
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/files
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/pap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/eap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/replicate
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/soh
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sql
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/sql/main/mysql/queries.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/logintime
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/exec
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/realm
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/preprocess
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/cache_eap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sradutmp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/expiration
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/detail
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/unpack
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/detail.log
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/expr
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/chap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/always
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sqlippool
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/sql/ippool/mysql/queries.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/dynamic_clients
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/utf8
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/attr_filter
including files in directory /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/cui
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/dhcp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/eap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/filter
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/abfab-tr
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/debug
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/canonicalization
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/accounting
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/control
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/moonshot-targeted-ids
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/rfc7542
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/policy.d/operator-name
including files in directory /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
main {
 security {
        user = "freerad"
        group = "freerad"
        allow_core_dumps = no
 }
        name = "freeradius"
        prefix = "/usr"
        localstatedir = "/var"
        logdir = "/var/log/freeradius"
        run_dir = "/var/run/freeradius"
}
main {
        name = "freeradius"
        prefix = "/usr"
        localstatedir = "/var"
        sbindir = "/usr/sbin"
        logdir = "/var/log/freeradius"
        run_dir = "/var/run/freeradius"
        libdir = "/usr/lib/freeradius"
        radacctdir = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct"
        hostname_lookups = no
        max_request_time = 30
        cleanup_delay = 5
        max_requests = 16384
        pidfile = "/var/run/freeradius/freeradius.pid"
        checkrad = "/usr/sbin/checkrad"
        debug_level = 0
        proxy_requests = yes
 log {
        stripped_names = no
        auth = no
        auth_badpass = no
        auth_goodpass = no
        colourise = yes
        msg_denied = "You are already logged in - access denied"
 }
 resources {
 }
 security {
        max_attributes = 200
        reject_delay = 1.000000
        status_server = yes
 }
}
radiusd: #### Loading Realms and Home Servers ####
 proxy server {
        retry_delay = 5
        retry_count = 3
        default_fallback = no
        dead_time = 120
        wake_all_if_all_dead = no
 }
 home_server localhost {
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
        port = 1812
        type = "auth"
        secret = <<< secret >>>
        response_window = 20.000000
        response_timeouts = 1
        max_outstanding = 65536
        zombie_period = 40
        status_check = "status-server"
        ping_interval = 30
        check_interval = 30
        check_timeout = 4
        num_answers_to_alive = 3
        revive_interval = 120
  limit {
        max_connections = 16
        max_requests = 0
        lifetime = 0
        idle_timeout = 0
  }
  coa {
        irt = 2
        mrt = 16
        mrc = 5
        mrd = 30
  }
 }
 home_server_pool my_auth_failover {
        type = fail-over
        home_server = localhost
 }
 realm example.com {
        auth_pool = my_auth_failover
 }
 realm LOCAL {
 }
radiusd: #### Loading Clients ####
Debugger not attached
systemd watchdog is disabled
 # Creating Auth-Type = mschap
 # Creating Auth-Type = eap
 # Creating Auth-Type = PAP
 # Creating Auth-Type = CHAP
 # Creating Auth-Type = MS-CHAP
radiusd: #### Instantiating modules ####
 modules {
  # Loaded module rlm_linelog
  # Loading module "linelog" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/linelog
  linelog {
        filename = "/var/log/freeradius/linelog"
        escape_filenames = no
        syslog_severity = "info"
        permissions = 384
        format = "This is a log message for %{User-Name}"
        reference = "messages.%{%{reply:Packet-Type}:-default}"
  }
  # Loading module "log_accounting" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/linelog
  linelog log_accounting {
        filename = "/var/log/freeradius/linelog-accounting"
        escape_filenames = no
        syslog_severity = "info"
        permissions = 384
        format = ""
        reference = "Accounting-Request.%{%{Acct-Status-Type}:-unknown}"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_digest
  # Loading module "digest" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/digest
  # Loaded module rlm_exec
  # Loading module "echo" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/echo
  exec echo {
        wait = yes
        program = "/bin/echo %{User-Name}"
        input_pairs = "request"
        output_pairs = "reply"
        shell_escape = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_radutmp
  # Loading module "radutmp" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/radutmp
  radutmp {
        filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radutmp"
        username = "%{User-Name}"
        case_sensitive = yes
        check_with_nas = yes
        permissions = 384
        caller_id = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_passwd
  # Loading module "etc_passwd" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/passwd
  passwd etc_passwd {
        filename = "/etc/passwd"
        format = "*User-Name:Crypt-Password:"
        delimiter = ":"
        ignore_nislike = no
        ignore_empty = yes
        allow_multiple_keys = no
        hash_size = 100
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_mschap
  # Loading module "mschap" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/mschap
  mschap {
        use_mppe = yes
        require_encryption = no
        require_strong = no
        with_ntdomain_hack = yes
   passchange {
   }
        allow_retry = yes
        winbind_retry_with_normalised_username = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_unix
  # Loading module "unix" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/unix
  unix {
        radwtmp = "/var/log/freeradius/radwtmp"
  }
Creating attribute Unix-Group
  # Loaded module rlm_files
  # Loading module "files" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/files
  files {
        filename = "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/files/authorize"
        acctusersfile = "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/files/accounting"
        preproxy_usersfile = "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/files/pre-proxy"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_pap
  # Loading module "pap" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/pap
  pap {
        normalise = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_eap
  # Loading module "eap" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/eap
  eap {
        default_eap_type = "md5"
        timer_expire = 60
        ignore_unknown_eap_types = no
        cisco_accounting_username_bug = no
        max_sessions = 16384
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_replicate
  # Loading module "replicate" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/replicate
  # Loaded module rlm_soh
  # Loading module "soh" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/soh
  soh {
        dhcp = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_sql
  # Loading module "sql" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sql
  sql {
        driver = "rlm_sql_mysql"
        server = "localhost"
        port = 3306
        login = "radius"
        password = <<< secret >>>
        radius_db = "radius"
        read_groups = yes
        read_profiles = yes
        read_clients = yes
        delete_stale_sessions = yes
        sql_user_name = "%{User-Name}"
        logfile = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/sql.log"
        default_user_profile = ""
        client_query = "SELECT id, nasname, shortname, type, secret, server FROM nas"
        authorize_check_query = "SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id"
        authorize_reply_query = "SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radreply WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id"
        authorize_group_check_query = "SELECT id, groupname, attribute, Value, op FROM radgroupcheck WHERE groupname = '%{SQL-Group}' ORDER BY id"
        authorize_group_reply_query = "SELECT id, groupname, attribute, value, op FROM radgroupreply WHERE groupname = '%{SQL-Group}' ORDER BY id"
        group_membership_query = "SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY priority"
        simul_count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM radacct WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' AND acctstoptime IS NULL"
        simul_verify_query = "SELECT radacctid, acctsessionid, username, nasipaddress, nasportid, framedipaddress, callingstationid, framedprotocol FROM radacct WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' AND acctstoptime IS NULL"
        safe_characters = "@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-_: /"
        auto_escape = no
   accounting {
        reference = "%{tolower:type.%{%{Acct-Status-Type}:-%{Request-Processing-Stage}}.query}"
    type {
     accounting-on {
        query = "UPDATE radacct SET acctstoptime = FROM_UNIXTIME(%{integer:Event-Timestamp}), acctsessiontime   = '%{integer:Event-Timestamp}' - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acctstarttime), acctterminatecause = '%{%{Acct-Terminate-Cause}:-NAS-Reboot}' WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL AND nasipaddress   = '%{NAS-IP-Address}' AND acctstarttime <= FROM_UNIXTIME(%{integer:Event-Timestamp})"
     }
     accounting-off {
        query = "UPDATE radacct SET acctstoptime = FROM_UNIXTIME(%{integer:Event-Timestamp}), acctsessiontime   = '%{integer:Event-Timestamp}' - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acctstarttime), acctterminatecause = '%{%{Acct-Terminate-Cause}:-NAS-Reboot}' WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL AND nasipaddress   = '%{NAS-IP-Address}' AND acctstarttime <= FROM_UNIXTIME(%{integer:Event-Timestamp})"
     }
     start {
        query = "INSERT INTO radacct (acctsessionid,            acctuniqueid,           username, realm,                        nasipaddress,           nasportid, nasporttype,         acctstarttime,          acctupdatetime, acctstoptime,acctsessiontime,        acctauthentic, connectinfo_start,       connectinfo_stop,       acctinputoctets, acctoutputoctets,      calledstationid,        callingstationid, acctterminatecause,   servicetype,            framedprotocol, framedipaddress,     framedipv6address,      framedipv6prefix, framedinterfaceid,    delegatedipv6prefix) VALUES ('%{Acct-Session-Id}', '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}', '%{SQL-User-Name}', '%{Realm}', '%{NAS-IP-Address}', '%{%{NAS-Port-ID}:-%{NAS-Port}}', '%{NAS-Port-Type}', FROM_UNIXTIME(%{integer:Event-Timestamp}), FROM_UNIXTIME(%{integer:Event-Timestamp}), NULL, '0', '%{Acct-Authentic}', '%{Connect-Info}', '', '0', '0', '%{Called-Station-Id}', '%{Calling-Station-Id}', '', '%{Service-Type}', '%{Framed-Protocol}', '%{Framed-IP-Address}', '%{Framed-IPv6-Address}', '%{Framed-IPv6-Prefix}', '%{Framed-Interface-Id}', '%{Delegated-IPv6-Prefix}')"
     }
     interim-update {
        query = "UPDATE radacct SET acctupdatetime  = (@acctupdatetime_old:=acctupdatetime), acctupdatetime  = FROM_UNIXTIME(%{integer:Event-Timestamp}), acctinterval    = %{integer:Event-Timestamp} - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@acctupdatetime_old), acctstoptime = NULL, framedipaddress = '%{Framed-IP-Address}', framedipv6address = '%{Framed-IPv6-Address}', framedipv6prefix = '%{Framed-IPv6-Prefix}', framedinterfaceid = '%{Framed-Interface-Id}', delegatedipv6prefix = '%{Delegated-IPv6-Prefix}', acctsessiontime = %{%{Acct-Session-Time}:-NULL}, acctinputoctets = '%{%{Acct-Input-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 | '%{%{Acct-Input-Octets}:-0}', acctoutputoctets = '%{%{Acct-Output-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 | '%{%{Acct-Output-Octets}:-0}' WHERE AcctUniqueId = '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}'"
     }
     stop {
        query = "UPDATE radacct SET acctstoptime        = FROM_UNIXTIME(%{integer:Event-Timestamp}), acctsessiontime    = %{%{Acct-Session-Time}:-NULL}, acctinputoctets        = '%{%{Acct-Input-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 | '%{%{Acct-Input-Octets}:-0}', acctoutputoctets = '%{%{Acct-Output-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 | '%{%{Acct-Output-Octets}:-0}', acctterminatecause = '%{Acct-Terminate-Cause}', connectinfo_stop = '%{Connect-Info}' WHERE AcctUniqueId = '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}'"
     }
    }
   }
   post-auth {
        reference = ".query"
        logfile = "/var/log/freeradius/post-auth.sql"
        query = "INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate) VALUES ( '%{SQL-User-Name}', '%{%{User-Password}:-%{Chap-Password}}', '%{reply:Packet-Type}', '%S')"
   }
  }
rlm_sql (sql): Driver rlm_sql_mysql (module rlm_sql_mysql) loaded and linked
Creating attribute SQL-Group
  # Loaded module rlm_logintime
  # Loading module "logintime" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/logintime
  logintime {
        minimum_timeout = 60
  }
  # Loading module "exec" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/exec
  exec {
        wait = no
        input_pairs = "request"
        shell_escape = yes
        timeout = 10
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_realm
  # Loading module "IPASS" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/realm
  realm IPASS {
        format = "prefix"
        delimiter = "/"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "suffix" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/realm
  realm suffix {
        format = "suffix"
        delimiter = "@"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "bangpath" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/realm
  realm bangpath {
        format = "prefix"
        delimiter = "!"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "realmpercent" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/realm
  realm realmpercent {
        format = "suffix"
        delimiter = "%"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loading module "ntdomain" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/realm
  realm ntdomain {
        format = "prefix"
        delimiter = "\\"
        ignore_default = no
        ignore_null = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_preprocess
  # Loading module "preprocess" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/preprocess
  preprocess {
        huntgroups = "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/preprocess/huntgroups"
        hints = "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/preprocess/hints"
        with_ascend_hack = no
        ascend_channels_per_line = 23
        with_ntdomain_hack = no
        with_specialix_jetstream_hack = no
        with_cisco_vsa_hack = no
        with_alvarion_vsa_hack = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_cache
  # Loading module "cache_eap" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/cache_eap
  cache cache_eap {
        driver = "rlm_cache_rbtree"
        key = "%{%{control:State}:-%{%{reply:State}:-%{State}}}"
        ttl = 15
        max_entries = 0
        epoch = 0
        add_stats = no
  }
  # Loading module "sradutmp" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sradutmp
  radutmp sradutmp {
        filename = "/var/log/freeradius/sradutmp"
        username = "%{User-Name}"
        case_sensitive = yes
        check_with_nas = yes
        permissions = 420
        caller_id = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_expiration
  # Loading module "expiration" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/expiration
  # Loaded module rlm_detail
  # Loading module "detail" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/detail
  detail {
        filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_unpack
  # Loading module "unpack" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/unpack
  # Loading module "auth_log" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail auth_log {
        filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/auth-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "reply_log" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail reply_log {
        filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/reply-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "pre_proxy_log" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail pre_proxy_log {
        filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/pre-proxy-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loading module "post_proxy_log" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/detail.log
  detail post_proxy_log {
        filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/post-proxy-detail-%Y%m%d"
        header = "%t"
        permissions = 384
        locking = no
        escape_filenames = no
        log_packet_header = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_expr
  # Loading module "expr" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/expr
  expr {
        safe_characters = "@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-_: /äéöüàâæçèéêëîïôœùûüaÿÄÉÖÜßÀÂÆÇÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸ"
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_chap
  # Loading module "chap" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/chap
  # Loading module "ntlm_auth" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth
  exec ntlm_auth {
        wait = yes
        program = "/path/to/ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=MYDOMAIN --username=%{mschap:User-Name} --password=%{User-Password}"
        shell_escape = yes
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_always
  # Loading module "reject" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/always
  always reject {
        rcode = "reject"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "fail" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/always
  always fail {
        rcode = "fail"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "ok" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/always
  always ok {
        rcode = "ok"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "handled" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/always
  always handled {
        rcode = "handled"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "invalid" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/always
  always invalid {
        rcode = "invalid"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "userlock" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/always
  always userlock {
        rcode = "userlock"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "notfound" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/always
  always notfound {
        rcode = "notfound"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "noop" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/always
  always noop {
        rcode = "noop"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loading module "updated" from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/always
  always updated {
        rcode = "updated"
        simulcount = 0
        mpp = no
  }
  # Loaded module rlm_sqlippool
```

Answer (score 0):

recreate radacct table with auto increment. it will fix it.
import the radacct table from freeradius github link.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).